# leftJoin method in Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel-5, left-join, eloquent

I'm beginner in Laravel and I'm using 5.5 version.

Is there a method leftJoin in Eloquent ORM?

I know there is one on DB facade (query builder), but if I want to use Eloquent only is there a leftJoin method?

Let's suppose, as an example, I have a model CarBrand and another one CarModel. 
CarBrand have a relationship type hasMany with CarModel, and CarModel belongsTo CarBrand.

Suppose I want to find CarBrand's id's without CarModel correspondence.

I found on this site, several responses like this:

```
CarBrand::leftJoin('CarModelTableName',
    'CarBrandTableName.id','=','CarModelTableName.carBrandId')->
    whereNull('CarModelTableName.carBrandId')->first();
```

I have checked and it does function as a left join :)

But in this case is *::leftJoin* an Eloquent method or silently it goes to DB facade?

I can't find any for leftJoin in Laravel 5 official docs other than DB facade.
Any links would be appreciated.

Hope I was clear,

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer....

I find out that I can use something like:

```
LaravelModellName::AnyQueryBuilderMethod
```

so that's why is using DB facade methods

The problem in my primary question could be solved 100% in eloquent way using doesntHave model method:

```
 $result = CarBrand::doesntHave('RelationshipNameWithCarModel')->get();
```